# Use of mvn clean -e install

Tags: maven, build

I am new to `maven build` process. Used the following command for building the project.

`mvn clean install`

But I am just confused over the command given below, found it is used somewhere else instead of above. Why we are using the following command?Is that `-e` a necessary or both the same?

`mvn -e clean install`

Checked for documentation. Some one please explain the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-e` is a maven execution flag which when set causes maven to "*Produce execution error messages*".

It will basically provide you with more information if something goes wrong.

So basically if the builds are both successful then there is no difference between executing `mvn -e clean install` or executing `mvn clean install`. However if something goes wrong then the 1st execution should provide more information which might make the problem easier to solve.

The `-e` flag is often used together with the `-X` flag, which produces execution debug output. Details can be found here:

http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_produce_execution_debug_output_or_error_messages

To see all flags available simply execute `mvn --help`